# get each cell textView data when click on button

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, uitextview, nsdictionary

I have a `UITableView` with `UITextView` in all the `cells`. I do have a bar button .On editing any of the `UITextView` and when I tap on the bar button all the `UITextView`s data must be stored in the form of `NSArray` of `dictionaries`. I will be thank full to you ,If I get out of this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't wait for your bar button to be pushed. If the table view is scrolled and the cells go off screen then any text entered by the user and not already saved will be lost.

Instead, your controller should be the delegate for all of the text fields. Whenever the text changes, save the change (probably using `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`) into a temporary array / dict. Now, when configuring your cells, enter the text from the temporary store into the cell text fields and when the bar button is pressed use your temporary store to save the entered text.

To get the text to save, assuming that the text field is tagged with the array index and that the array contains mutable dictionaries (you should consider adding some protection and error logging):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *stringToSave = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"Save me: %@", stringToSave);

    NSMutableDictionary *storeDict = [self.storeArray objectAtIndex:textField.tag];
    [storeDict setObject:stringToSave forKey:@"description"];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How to save ,I mean all should be in the form of array of dictionaries ,and how can we identify that which text view gonna changing,on a long run I have to submit all the text view's text as array of Dictionaries

Comment: Depends on the structure you need to save in, how do the dictionaries apply? I guess the array order matches the order of your cells?

Comment: Can u please write the code what i have to write in (textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)

Comment: That's how you get the text to save, but how you store it I can't be sure of. You could add a tag to the text field so you know what row it is (and the index to your array).

Comment: My array of Dictionary format is  thoughts =     (
                {
            "_id" = 51bc0ccb988d605f79000018;
            "category_ids" =             (
                "Question,Doubt,Idea,"
            );
            "created_at" = "2013-06-15T06:42:19Z";
            description = Siva;
            "idea_id" = 51bc0cb7988d605f79000017;
            "updated_at" = "2013-06-15T06:42:19Z";
        }
    );

Comment: i need to replace the textview data in the place of Description

Comment: so the array and dictionary are already setup, and the dictionary in the array is mutable ?

Comment: Yes these data coming from server but the user able to modify the Description (Textview) and Category_Ids.

Comment: Hi i am getting error like 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x816c3c0'

Comment: So your array doesn't contain mutable dictionaries. When you create the array, make the dictionaries mutable if you want to edit them later...